# how to lock a variable at server for a time period

Tags: java, php, logic, mutex

I have a specific variable which i get it from server and have to return it to server. But until my processing is completed on that variable, no one should access it i.e, i want to lock that variable at server. I'm programming in Php. 
Kindly some one give an idea on how to do it..

Comment: Show some code of what you are doing plz.

Comment: I'm still at scratch level. I get data as XML file(bus seat info), i store it in Database, I present seat layout on my page & when user clicks on a seat & proceeds for payment, I have to block that seat at server & release it after i receive payment. How can i do it??

Comment: which database you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Your best choice is to make an additional column in your data table in which you insert a timestamp when a user wants to reserve the seat. Consider that the user may also simply walk away and never complete the reservation, so you cannot simply keep it locked indefinitely. So enter the current time into the row to flag it as reserved. When checking whether a seat is free, consider all flags older than X (decide what X should be) as expired, because the user apparently never followed through.

Comment: I get seat data each time from different APIs a bus is viewed. So for example I would like to block it for 5mins, what I'm unable to get is- how could i block the seat data(which is in XML format) at all their servers??

Comment: So the actual reservation is happening through an API on "their" servers, and other people are using those APIs as well? Then unless their API offers some kind of locking mechanism, I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: Yes, that is what is bothering me.. & Now we r gonna create an API in SOAP ourselves & offer it to other bus operators--In this case I can place row locking on that particular seat row. Will that be enough??

Comment: It's hard to answer "Will that be enough" when having so few details. You can lock your own database that way, yes. If you're depending on another service that does not allow locking though, all you can do is try-and-fail (try to reserve the seat through the API, fail if it has already been taken in the meantime).

Answer (score 0):

The PHP is a shared-nothing environment so no one will access to the variable (even it is a static or global) except the current user.

Comment: I'm still at scratch level. I get data as XML file(bus seat info), i store it in Database, I present seat layout on my page & when user clicks on a seat & proceeds for payment, I have to block that seat at server & release it after i receive payment. How can i do it??

Comment: The you should apply pessimistic concurrency at the database interaction layer.

Answer (score 0):

I think to implement this you have to do something at table from where you taking seats.
Like, set something In the table - a boolean, timestamp, deleting the row, flag etc - that indicates that you've processed or processing the row.

OR

You can use row locking concept of mysql database.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html